# How to merge flags, defined in other package, into cobra.flags?

Tags: go, cobra

Some definition in `sig.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client/config/config.go`:

```
var (
    kubeconfig, apiServerURL string
)

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&kubeconfig, "kubeconfig", "",
        "Paths to a kubeconfig. Only required if out-of-cluster.")
}
```

my project, mybinary, with cobra

```
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mybinary",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        somefunc()
    }
}
func init() {
    rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVar(&cfgFile, "config", "", "config file")
    rootCmd.InitDefaultHelpFlag()
}
```

What do I need to do if I want to use `mybinary --kubeconfig somevalue` to set param `kubeconfig` defined upon `config.go`?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, but I think for now your best bet is probably to use cobra's `PersistentPreRun` function:

```golang
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
        // ...
        PersistentPreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
                flag.CommandLine.Parse([]string{"-kubeconfig", yourVariableHere})
        },
        // ...
}
```

That is, before your root command runs, or any of the commands that are derived from it (provided they don't override the PreRun), you'll call the equivalent of calling `flag.Parse()` as if someone had run:

```
your-program -kubeconfig <string>
```

where the  value is from the argument provided to your own Cobra flag.  You could use your `cfgFile` argument if that's the right thing, or add a `--kubeconfig` variable.

If you're using [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper), it seems to have its own glue for mixing with the basic `flag` library, but I have not investigated this.  I do see, in [config.go](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/master/pkg/client/config/config.go), this comment:

```
// TODO: Fix this to allow double vendoring this library but still register flags on behalf of users
```

which, if fixed, would provide a way other than calling `flag.CommandLine.Parse`.